# Unable to authenticate to Twitter

Tags: apex

I am try to implement OAuth for twitter in salesforce. Here is my apex class

```
public class PRO_TwitterUtils{

    private SocialNetworkConfigs__c service;
    private String token;
    private String tokenSecret;
    private Boolean isAccess = false;
    private String verifier;

    private String nonce;
    private String timestamp;
    private String signature;
    private String consumerKey;
    private String consumerSecret;

    private Map<String,String> parameters = new Map<String,String>();

    public String message { get; set; }

    public String callbackUrl {get; set; }

    public void setConsumerKey(String value) { consumerKey = value; }
    public void setConsumerSecret(String value) { consumerSecret = value; }

    String serviceName='Twitter';
    String redirectTo='apex/PRO_TwitterAuthorize';

    //URL CONFIGS
    String requestTokenURL ='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token';
    String twitterOauthUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate';
    String twitterTokenUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token';   

    public PRO_TwitterUtils(){
        String current =System.URL.getCurrentRequestUrl().toExternalForm();   
        callbackUrl =  current.replace('apex/PRO_SocialNetworkAuth',redirectTo);            
    }

    /**

     * returns the authorization URL that the user should be redirected to
     * If null is returned, the request failed. and it would throw a excdeeptiom
     */ 
    public Pagereference login() {

        service =SocialNetworkConfigs__c.getInstance(serviceName);

        if(service==null || service.consumerkey__c==null || service.ConsumerSecret__c==null) {
            throw new CustomException('Missing Configuartion');                      
            return null;                
        }

        if(callbackUrl==null) { 
            if(ApexPages.currentPage()==null || ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Host')==null) {               
                throw new CustomException('No callback page was set and it couldn\'t be generated from Apex context');                      
                return null;
            }


        }

        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint(requestTokenURL);
        System.debug('Request body set to: '+req.getBody());
        consumerKey = service.consumerkey__c;
        consumerSecret = service.consumersecret__c;
        sign(req);
        HttpResponse res = null;

        res = h.send(req);
        System.debug('Response from request token request: ('+res.getStatusCode()+')'+res.getBody());
        if(res.getStatusCode()>299) {
            throw new CustomException('Failed getting a request token');                
            return null;
        }
        String resParams = serviceName == 'test1234' ? 
            'oauth_token=token&oauth_token_secret=token_secret' : res.getBody();

        Map<String,String> rp = getUrlParams(resParams);

        User u =[Select Twitter_Access_Token__c,Twitter_Token_Secret__c from user where id=:userinfo.getUserId()];


        u.Twitter_Access_Token__c = rp.get('oauth_token');
        u.Twitter_Token_Secret__c = rp.get('oauth_token_secret');

        update u;

        System.debug('Got request token: '+u.Twitter_Access_Token__c+'('+rp.get('oauth_token')+')');

        String authuri= twitterOauthUrl+'?oauth_token='+EncodingUtil.urlDecode(u.Twitter_Access_Token__c,'UTF-8')+'&oauth_consumer_key='+service.consumerkey__c+'&redirect_uri='+callbackURL;
        return new PageReference(authuri);
    }

    public Pagereference completeAuthorization() {
        System.debug('Completing authorization for request token '+token+' with verifier '+verifier);
        String token = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oauth_token');
        String verifier = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oauth_verifier');

        User u =[Select Twitter_Last_Authenticated_On__c,Twitter_Access_Token__c,Twitter_Token_Secret__c from user where id=:userinfo.getUserId()];


        service =SocialNetworkConfigs__c.getInstance(serviceName);

        consumerKey = service.ConsumerKey__c;
        consumerSecret = service.ConsumerSecret__c;
        this.token = u.Twitter_Access_Token__c;
        tokenSecret = u.Twitter_Token_Secret__c;

        if(verifier!=null) {
            this.verifier = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(verifier,'UTF-8');
        }

        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint(twitterTokenUrl);
        req.setBody('');
        sign(req);
        HttpResponse res = null;
        res = h.send(req);
        System.debug('Response from request token request: ('+res.getStatusCode()+')'+res.getBody());

        if(res.getStatusCode()>299) {
            return null;
        }

        String resParams = service.name == 'test1234' ? 
            'oauth_token=token&oauth_token_secret=token_secret' : res.getBody();

        Map<String,String> rp = new Map<String,String>();
        for(String s : resParams.split('&')) {
            List<String> kv = s.split('=');
            rp.put(kv[0],kv[1]);
            System.debug('Access token response param: '+kv[0]+'='+kv[1]);
        }

        u.Twitter_Access_Token__c = rp.get('oauth_token');
        u.Twitter_Token_Secret__c = rp.get('oauth_token_secret');
        u.Twitter_Last_Authenticated_On__c = datetime.now();
        update u;
        return new PageReference('/apex/PRO_SocialNetworkAuth');
    }




    private void refreshParameters() {
        parameters.clear();

        parameters.put('oauth_callback',callbackUrl);
        parameters.put('oauth_consumer_key',consumerKey);
        parameters.put('oauth_nonce',nonce);

        parameters.put('oauth_signature_method','HMAC-SHA1');
        parameters.put('oauth_timestamp',timestamp);
        if(token!=null) {
            parameters.put('oauth_token',token);
        }
        if(verifier!=null) {
            parameters.put('oauth_verifier',verifier);
        }
        parameters.put('oauth_version','1.0');
    }

    private Map<String,String> getUrlParams(String value) {

        Map<String,String> res = new Map<String,String>();
        if(value==null || value=='') {
            return res;
        }
        for(String s : value.split('&')) {
            System.debug('getUrlParams: '+s);
            List<String> kv = s.split('=');
            if(kv.size()>1) {
                System.debug('getUrlParams:  -> '+kv[0]+','+kv[1]);
                res.put(kv[0],kv[1]);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    private String createBaseString(Map<String,String> oauthParams, HttpRequest req) {
        Map<String,String> p = oauthParams.clone();
        if(req.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase('post') && req.getBody()!=null && 
           req.getHeader('Content-Type')=='application/x-www-form-urlencoded') {
            p.putAll(getUrlParams(req.getBody()));
        }
        String host = req.getEndpoint();
        Integer n = host.indexOf('?');
        if(n>-1) {
            p.putAll(getUrlParams(host.substring(n+1)));
            host = host.substring(0,n);
        }
        List<String> keys = new List<String>();
        keys.addAll(p.keySet());
        keys.sort();
        String s = keys.get(0)+'='+p.get(keys.get(0));
        for(Integer i=1;i<keys.size();i++) {
            s = s + '&' + keys.get(i)+'='+p.get(keys.get(i));
        }

        // According to OAuth spec, host string should be lowercased, but Google and LinkedIn
        // both expect that case is preserved.
        return req.getMethod().toUpperCase()+ '&' + 
            EncodingUtil.urlEncode(host, 'UTF-8') + '&' +
            EncodingUtil.urlEncode(s, 'UTF-8');
    }

    public void sign(HttpRequest req) {

        nonce = PRO_FacebookUtils.getRandomNonce();
        timestamp = String.valueOf(DateTime.now().getTime()/1000);

        refreshParameters();

        String s = createBaseString(parameters, req);

        System.debug('Signature base string: '+s);

        Blob sig = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA1', Blob.valueOf(s), 
                       Blob.valueOf(EncodingUtil.urlEncode(consumerSecret, 'UTF-8')+'&'+
                                    (tokenSecret!=null ? EncodingUtil.urlEncode(tokenSecret, 'UTF-8') : '')));
        signature = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.base64encode(sig), 'UTF-8');
        System.debug('Signature: '+signature);

        String header = 'OAuth ';
        for (String key : parameters.keySet()) {
            header = header + key + '="'+parameters.get(key)+'", ';
        }
        header = header + 'oauth_signature="'+signature+'"'; 

        System.debug('Authorization: '+header);
        req.setHeader('Authorization',header);  
    }

    public PageReference logout(){
        return null;
    }
    public class CustomException extends Exception{}
}
```

When ever i call the login button it always result in error 
 (401)Failed to validate oauth signature and token

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is helpful...this code works for me but it uses oAuth2 to do the authentication with Twitter. I use a custom setting to store my creds because I am not doing user level authentication, but I believe the principle is the same. Two classes - one to get the bearer token, one to use it to authenticate and execute a query against the Twitter API:

```
private String getBearerToken() {
//Encode them
String keyencoded = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(socialsettings.API_Key__c, 'UTF-8');
String secretkeyencoded = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(socialsettings.API_Secret_Key__c, 'UTF-8');

//Create Final Key String
String sFinal = keyencoded + ':' + secretkeyencoded;
//Convert to Blob
Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(sFinal);

//Build Request
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token');
req.setMethod('POST');

//Add Auth Header
String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

//You need to add this to the request - proved easy to miss in instructions...
req.setBody('grant_type=client_credentials');

//Make request
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
String stoken;
//Parse JSON for Bearer Token
JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());
while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME && parser.getText() == 'access_token'){
parser.nextToken();
stoken = parser.getText();
}
}
//Return Token so it can be used in next call
return stoken;
}
```

This is the class that calls Twitter after calling this bearer token method

```
private void submittotwitter () {
    HttpRequest req2 = new HttpRequest();
    //I actually store the endpoint in the same custom setting and build dynamically, but for purposes of demo:
    req2.setEndpoint('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=britishboyindc,salesforce');
    req2.setMethod('GET');

    //Call Bearer token Method
    //Note - unless invalidated, I believe you can store this and keep using it indefinitely, but again, to demo concept
    String authorizationHeader = 'Bearer ' + getBearerToken();
    req2.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req2);
    String sBody = res.getBody();

    //I have a Twitter Results class to de-serialize the results into (See below)
    Map <String, TwitterResults> TwitterResultsMap = new Map<String, TwitterResults> ();

    //You can generate one here: http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/makeApex
    //I can then pass the results back as a return, or set the map as s public variable on the class

    //Use native JSON parser to turn results into a list of TwitterResults
    List tresults = TwitterResults.parse(sBody);
    //The key is set to be the twitter handle name that I am storing in SFDC
    For (TwitterResults t: tresults) {
    TwitterResultsMap.put(t.screen_name, t);
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using old OAuth code. Try using this version of `getUrlParams` - it properly encodes parameter names and values.

```
private Map<String,String> getUrlParams(String value) {

    Map<String,String> res = new Map<String,String>();
    if(value==null || value=='') {
        return res;
    }
    for(String s : value.split('&')) {
        System.debug('getUrlParams: '+s);
        List<String> kv = s.split('=');
        if(kv.size()>1) {
          // RFC 5849 section 3.4.1.3.1 and 3.4.1.3.2 specify that parameter names 
          // and values are decoded then encoded before being sorted and concatenated
          // Section 3.6 specifies that space must be encoded as %20 and not +
          String encName = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.urlDecode(kv[0], 'UTF-8'), 'UTF-8').replace('+','%20');
          String encValue = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.urlDecode(kv[1], 'UTF-8'), 'UTF-8').replace('+','%20');
          System.debug('getUrlParams:  -> '+encName+','+encValue);
          res.put(encName,encValue);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: No still continue to get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a URLencode problem. Did you URLencode the callback URL? If not, you might want to give it a try.

```
String encoded = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(url, 'UTF-8');
```